# Oracle stored Procedure to return multiple resultsets to .net

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have written the following stored procedure to return multiple data sets to my front end .Net application

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEE_INFO 
(
  EMP_NO IN VARCHAR2,
  E_RECORD_SET1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  E_RECORD_SET2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  E_RECORD_SET3 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  E_RECORD_SET4 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN E_RECORD_SET1 FOR
    SELECT * FROM EMP.EMPLOYEES;

  OPEN E_RECORD_SET2 FOR
    SELECT * FROM EMP.CITIES;

  OPEN E_RECORD_SET3 FOR
    SELECT * FROM EMP.STATES;

  OPEN E_RECORD_SET1 FOR
    SELECT * FROM EMP.DURATION;
```

Each query executes correctly on its own.  When I execute the stored procedure, it displays the result sets but I don't believe that all the data is being fetched.  At the bottom, it still says "RUNNING IDE CONNECTION".

- Is the procedure looping?
- Is there a limitation regarding the `SYS_REFCURSOR` type?
- Do I need to close these cursors?

Answer (score 0):

- I assume that your actual stored procedure is not missing the `END` at the end.  The code you posted won't compile.
- I assume that your stored procedure is also doing something with the `EMP_NO` parameter.
- And I assume that despite the name implying that it is a number, `EMP_NO` is actually declared as a string.

Assuming all that is true

- Why do you believe that all the data is not being fetched?
- What is the "it" that the sentence "At the bottom, it still says" refers to?  Is this your C# application?  Your IDE?  Something else?
- The code you posted, assuming the `END` is added so that it compiles, cannot loop.  Your code simply opens the cursors, it does not execute the SQL statements and it does not generate any data.  That won't happen until the client application starts fetching data.
- Although it is an unusual design, it is perfectly syntactically valid to have a procedure that returns four `SYS_REFCURSOR` parameters.  That won't affect the data that is fetched from the cursors.
- Yes, your client application needs to close these cursors once it has fetched all the data from them.

Comment: hey Justin thanks for the response, here are my answers to your questions. firstly the emp_no will be used in the where clause which i will implement in a couple of days. the emp_no is a varchar and yes i have end at the end of the stored proc. the "it" refers to the output log dialog box which is opened when i execute the stored proc using oracle sql developer. also you suggested this is an unusal design, could you please suggest a more robust desing as im new to oracle, do i need to use a cursor in oracle to return a record set from a stored proc ? also how would i close the cursors ?

Comment: Justin thanks for the response, 
here are my answers to your questions. 
firstly the emp_no will be used in the where clause which i will implement in a couple of days. 
the emp_no is a varchar and yes i have end at the end of the stored proc.
 the "it" refers to the output log dialog box which is opened when i execute the stored proc using oracle sql developer. 
also you suggested this is an unusual design, could you please suggest a more robust design as I’m new to oracle, 
do i need to use a cursor in oracle to return a record set from a stored proc ? 
also how would i close the cursors ?

Comment: @JustinRusso - Normally, you would either have separate procedures or you would return a single `SYS_REFCURSOR` that had the results of joining the four tables in question together. You wouldn't want to try to roll your own pesudo-join logic in your client application. If you are merely executing this stored procedure from SQL Developer (in which case the c# and .net tags don't seem to apply) SQL Developer will close the cursors. When you are writing your C# code to call this procedure, your C# code will need to close the cursors.

Comment: can you please provide a brief syntax for my code sample on how to close the cursors in the procedure ?

Comment: @JustinRusso - You wouldn't close the cursors in the procedure.  If you did, the client application would not be able to fetch any data from them.  When you are writing your C# code to call this procedure, your C# code will need to close the cursors.